# How to iterate over a comma separated string in template?

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a template which is supposed to iterate over a string containing names of photos, like

`photo.1jpg, photo2.jpg, photo3.jpg`

and show all of the photos in a lot like this:

```
{{ if .article.Photos }}
  {{ range $photo := .article.Photos }}
      <img src="/path/to/{{$photo}}" />
  {{end}}
{{ endif }}
```

I'm wondering how can I acheive this in template without changing the data structure of `article`?

Comment: With a template function https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#example_Template_func

Comment: @Adrian I thought about template function but could not figure out how to use them to split a string and convert it to a slice. Hence the question.

Comment: Adrian's comment shows how to use template functions. Split a string on `, ` using `func(s string) []string { return strings.Split(photos, ", ") }`.  Use a regex if the whitespace following the comma varies.

Comment: Thanks for the tip guys. Worked great!